# Separate spring-boot apps with embedded databases conflict

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have two spring-boot applications which both use embedded h2 databases, pointing to different db files in different directories. The only use for the h2 database is a simple internal login for administrative tasks for the respective applications. If I have both started up on the same machine at the same time the two applications conflict; i.e. logging into one app logs you out of the other app.

I thought with them using different database url's, pointing to different files in different directories, with the engine running in embedded mode in separate apps, there would not be any conflict.

The apps are configured as standalone with embedded tomcat. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It appears the database is not the culprit. Even though the separate apps are running on different ports there appears to be some collusion between the apps, maybe via the embedded tomcat. More investigations to do on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies with no path are shared between servers running on the same host. You probably just need to give one if them a context path (as in `server.contextPath`).